# Ubuntu 12.04, broken update manager, phpmyadmin, and many other things

Tags: 12.04, update-manager, phpmyadmin

I'm using Ubuntu **12.04** with **XFCE**

My story is a more than a week long, but from today I have lot of strange problems with system and **apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin, update manager**, and some other.

I had apache2, mysql and phpmyadmin working without any troubles.
Story begins from installing and configuring system for **SSH**. I changed some settings in **hosts** file and some permissions in **/home/user** and some other witch I don't remember now. 
As I discovered later my apache2, mysql and phpmyadmin didn't work at all.
After lot of googling and trying many settings, reinstalling packages I solved problems with apache2 and mysql, they do work, but **phpmyadmin** still doesn't work.

1. When I enter `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` I got

`Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.`

In time of this story **I made all possible system updates by update manager**, like I always do.

1. After some reboot I noticed that my terminal have all **key shortcuts blank!** But before they were like ctrl+shift+t, ctrl+shift+c, etc.
2. My update manager crashed

`could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open 13 permission denied.`

I didn't change any permissions there

1. **plymouth, metacity** crashed too.

I reinstalled them, and now I not saw crash reports about them. 
I reinstalled also **dbconfig-common**.

1. My **icon of internet connection dissapeard** from the top bar, but I can open "network connections" from apps menu and internet is working.
2. All of the above I make in **xfce**, but when I switched to **Unity 2D** I saw all **windows are without borders**.

I found that I should use `unity --replace` so I did but it don't work

```
   $ unity --replace 

Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
    Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
    Backend     : gconf
    Integration : true
    Profile     : unity
    Adding plugins
    Initializing core options...done
    compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1e00004

    compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1400002

    compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1200002

    compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x3000004

    Initializing composite options...done
    Initializing opengl options...done
    Initializing decor options...done
    Initializing vpswitch options...done
    Initializing snap options...done
    Initializing mousepoll options...done
    Initializing resize options...done
    Initializing place options...done
    Initializing move options...done
    Initializing wall options...done
    Initializing grid options...done
    Initializing session options...done
    Initializing gnomecompat options...done
    Initializing animation options...done
    Initializing fade options...done
    Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
    Initializing workarounds options...done
    Initializing scale options...done
    compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
    Initializing expo options...done
    Initializing ezoom options...done

    (compiz:15150): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
    WARN  2012-12-22 02:56:45 unity.ibus <unknown>:0 Unable to load /var/lib/dbus/machine-id: Failed to open file '/var/lib/dbus/machine-id': Permission denied
    Initializing unityshell options...done
    compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x3200090!
    compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
    compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x3200093!
    compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
    compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x3200096!
    compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
    compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x3200099!
    compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
    ERROR 2012-12-22 02:56:46 unity.glib-gobject <unknown>:0 g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
    Starting gtk-window-decorator
    compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
    compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
```

I have no idea why so many things are broken and I even don't know where to begin repairs. I'm googling from hours and days. Please help, give some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after few more days of searching answers I just made a backup of important files and reinstalled whole system. It was the fastest solution.

Now, after 2 months, new system is still working very well.